# What is the largest value of $n$ where $\lg(n) \le 1,000,000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the largest value of $n$ where $\lg(n) \le 1,000,000$ is the question that has been posed in a book I am currently working through and the answer is $2^{10^6}$. However I'm not sure how to get there. This is what I did:

$\lg(n) \le 1000000$

$e^{\lg(n)} \le e^{1000000}$

$n \le e^{1000000}$

But then I don't know where to go from that to get the desired number.

Comment: Maybe the book meant the *binary* logarithm?

Comment: The symbol $\operatorname{lg}$ typically refers to the logarithm with base 2.

Comment: @Bernard Of course it does, thank you!

Comment: @AustinMohr Yeah, thanks that's exactly what it's referring to!

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen "lg" before.

Comment: But basically the greatest value of any $\log_b n \le W$ is going be $ n \le b^W$.

Comment: Note that $10^6=1000000$, so $2^{1000000}=2^{10^6}$.  "*But then I don't know where to go from that to get the desired number.*"  You already got the desired number...

Comment: @JMoravitz yeah my question got edited, I had it as $e^{1000000}$ not what it is now.

Comment: If the initial two comments solved your question, perhaps you might consider writing an answer yourself below detailing what you discovered or deleting the question so as to remove this question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters pointing out that lg is log base 2 so the solution is as follows:

$\lg(n) \le 1000000$

$n \le 2^{1000000}$

$n \le 2^{10^6}$